# How to PATCH collection using Symfony2 Forms and REST?

Tags: rest, symfony, symfony-forms

Here is my form field:

```
        $builder->add('settings', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new UserSettingType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ));
```

Here is the data I'm trying to send:

```
{ 
    "user": {
        "settings": [
                {"name": "use_signature", "value": "yes"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is the data that I currently have:

```
{ 
    "user": {
        "settings": [
                {"name": "use_signature", "value": "no"},
                {"name": "signature", "value": "blah-blah-blah"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is how I handle the request (controller):

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
    $form->submit($request, $request->getMethod() !== 'PATCH');

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->flush();

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);

        return $response;
    }
```

The problem is that when I PATCH the data, the "signature" setting is removed from the "settings" collection. However, if I do the same with any direct field of the "user" entity, PATCH request is handled properly (only the field that is included in the request is being changed, and nothing else is being deleted or set to null).

Is there any idea on how to handle this in case of OneToMany collection (i.e. I want to change only one particular setting or some of them, but not all)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this using 
`orphanRemoval=true`
on the OneToMany side! I'm also using entity as formtype with `'multiple' => true`

Comment: This solved my issue! Very nice!, wonder what would happen if the childs have childs themselves and an error occurrs, I guess that at that point is a matter of handling the 500 exception..